# Kill a VBScript from another VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript

Is there any way to kill a `wscript.exe` (windows process for vb script) from another VBScript (not from the currently executing `wscript`)?

If I create a script like this:

```
Set s = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
s.Run "taskkill /im wscript.exe", , True
```

instead of killing the former script, this will kill itself.

Comment: Got it 
s.Run "taskkill.exe /F /IM wscript.exe /T" will do it :)

Comment: Please edit your question if you need to provide clarification/additional information. I took the liberty to do it for you this time.

Comment: `taskkill.exe /F /IM wscript.exe /T` will kill *all* `wscript.exe` processes, including its own parent.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using WMI for selecting and terminating the processes. Something like this should work:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='wscript.exe' AND NOT " & _
      "CommandLine LIKE '%" & Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\", "\\") & "%'"

For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  p.Terminate
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Option Explicit

Dim strScriptToKill
    strScriptToKill = "ItIsDead.vbs"

Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery ( _ 
        "Select * from Win32_Process " & _ 
        "WHERE (Name = 'cscript.exe' OR Name = 'wscript.exe') " & _ 
        "AND Commandline LIKE '%"& strScriptToKill &"%'" _ 
    )
    For Each objProcess in colProcess
        objProcess.Terminate()
    Next
```