# Script to emulate physical keyboard press so that PC stays awake

Tags: windows, vba, batch-file

I'm looking for a solution to an issue caused by an active directory policy. I use a development desktop PC however that sits under my desk in the office. That PC has a policy on it that puts it to sleep if no keyboard / mouse activity is detected for 4 hours. This is common in my case as I use remote desktop to connect to the machine rather than physically sitting at it.

I've done the logical thing and spoken to IT about getting the PC put into a differnt OU with the policy removed but they haven't acted on this yet and it is really causing me issues. (Easy if you are in the office but a pain if you are working from home!)

So I wondered if there was a simple script I could run that would press the caps lock key twice every 3 hours - but in a way that would be seen by the PC as a physical key press rather than just a script running.

Alternatively I could look into making a usb thumdrive that acts as a keyboard but I think I'd run into security issues there!

Regards

Comment: Same answers as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457907/how-to-prevent-auto-locking-feature-of-an-xp-machine-using-vbscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The link of where this information was extracted](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html)

The Send Keys method simulates real key strokes.
Here's an example from the same website.

```
Sub CommentAddOrEdit()
  Dim cmt As Comment
   Set cmt = ActiveCell.Comment
    If cmt Is Nothing Then
     ActiveCell.AddComment text:=""
    End If
 SendKeys "+{F2}"
End Sub
```

Also it comes with a nice table that translates every key in your keyboard, for the caps lock as you wanted it would be :

{CAPSLOCK}.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up using the send keys method to do this although the script you provided assumes that a worksheet is active I think. Instead I built a quick qindows form application that can run this in the background with a delay.

Comment: @user2916488 oh.. I totally forgot about the "background" part, glad it helped in some way tho!

Answer (score -1):

I have just found something ready to use:

http://www.symantec.com/connect/downloads/readynosleepexe-prevents-screensaver-and-pc-locking

It does not exactly do what you are asking for, but helps to solve your initial problem.

It moves your cursor side to side by a couple of pixels.

Following the link you could find a zip with .exe and source file in it.
The source file can be changed ( for example, to change the timeout ) and recompiled by this tool:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/compiler.htm

This .exe has an icon in the tray to provide a way to stop it ( or you can just kill the process from the process manager ). it also needs less than 1 MB of RAM.

Comment: Thank you, yes the application does look like what I need although I couldn't download the compiler at work due to policy restrictions so couldn't try it out here. Instead I built my own windows form applciation that does the same thing.