# Chrome Authentication using AutoIt - Desktop locked situation

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, autoit

Trying to handle the Chrome's authentication pop up ("Authentication required") using the Autoit

Sceanrio -

1. Navigate to URL from chrome
2. Chrome displays "Authentication Required" Pop up
3. Enter credentials and proceed

The below code snippet works just fine except when the system/desktop is in locked state. Any help will be appreciated.

```
WinWait("", "Authentication Required", 10)
If WinExists("","Authentication Required") Then
 Send("username"{Tab}")
 Send("password{Enter}")
EndIf
```

Alternate options tried -

1. Autoit WIndow info finder - Didn't identified the window information like class, title etc for chrome
2. alert.authenticateUsing() - Doesn't work as the pop is not from DOM and its awindows pop up
3. driver.navigate("http://username:password@domain") - Didn't worked in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIT won't work if the window is locked. What you can do is, you can do following things to prevent window from being locked

1. Change the power option to keep always on
2. Write down a vbscript which keeps on sending some keys and schedule it using windows scheduler. 
   [How to prevent auto-locking feature of an XP machine using VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457907/how-to-prevent-auto-locking-feature-of-an-xp-machine-using-vbscript)